# SQL - Is there a way to check rows for duplicates in all columns of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a big table with over 1 million rows and 96 columns.

Using SQL I want to find rows where every value is the same. The table doesn't have any primary key so I'm not sure how to approach this. I'm not permitted to change the table structure.

I've seen people use count(*) and group by but I'm not sure if this is effective for a table with 96 columns.

Comment: Are there two columns that are hardly ever the same?

Answer (score 2):

Using `COUNT()` as an analytic function we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, ..., col96) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT col1, col2, ..., col96
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, use `BINARY_CHECKSUM`:

```
with cte as (
    select *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) checksum
    from mytable
), cte2 as (
    select checksum
    from cte
    group by checksum
    having count(*) > 1
)
select distinct t1.*
from cte t1
join cte t2 on t1.checksum = t2.checksum
  and t1.col1 = t2.col2
  and t1.col2 = t2.col2
  -- etc
where t1.checksum in (select checksum from cte2)
```

`cte2` will return (almost) only truly matching rows, so join condition won't have many rows to exhaustively compare every column.

Comment: BINARY_CHECKSUM is a good approach for identifying duplicate candidate rows, though I think the original poster was asking for a way to identify rows where all of the column values are the same (e.g. 'A','A','A','A',...'A'), not duplicate rows.

Comment: @C.White I doubt it. All answers assume the same values must appear for the same columns of different rows. In other words, OP wants to find duplicate rows. Another way of looking at it is finding rows that have all columns with the same value is trivial and not worthy of a question here.

Comment: Checking a few columns for uniqueness is trivial, but validating that 96 different columns are equal doesn't strike me as trivial (unless there is some obvious trick I'm missing).

Comment: @C.White `where col1 = col2 and col1 = col3 and col1 = col4 and etc`. Tedious, but trivial.

Answer (score 1):

you can use md5 function as primary key.

```
select count(1),md5_col,* from ( 
select md5(concat_ws('',col1,col2)) as md5_col,* from db_name.table_name) tt group by md5_col;
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than trying to boil the ocean and solve the entire problem with a single sql query (which you certainly *can* do...), I recommend using any indexes or statistics on the tables to filter out as many rows as you can.

Start by finding the columns with the most / fewest unique values (assuming you have statistics, that is), and smash them up against each other to rapidly exclude as many rows as possible. Take the results, dump them to a temp table, index fields as needed, and repeat.

Or you could just do this:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max);
Select @sql='select column1 from schema.table where case ' + stuff((select 'when col1!=' + quotename(name) + ' then 0 ' from sys.columns where object_id=object_id('schema.table') for xml path(''),Type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,11,'') + 'else 1 end = 1';
Exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you must run that horrorshow of a query in production, please use snapshot isolation or move it to a temp table first (unless no one ever updates the table.

(Honestly, I would probably use something like that query on the temp table containing my filtered-down dataset... but anything you can do to makes sure that the comparisons aren't naïve (e.g. taking statistics into account) can improve your performance significantly. If you want to do it all at once, you could always join sys.tables to a temp table that puts your field comparisons into a thoughtful order. After all, once a case statement if found to be true, all the others will be skipped for that record. )